# Logically determine a composite key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I'm working with an MSSQL table that does not have a primary or unique key contstraint defined.  There are two fields, lets call them xId and yId, that I believe together would be a composite key, but I want to confirm this by examining the data.

I'm thinking that I should be able to write a SQL count statement that I can compare to the total number of records on the table that would logically determine if the combination of xId and yId (or a third column id necessary) could in fact act as a composite key.  However, I'm having trouble coming up with the right GROUP BY or other type of clause that would confirm or disprove this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select xid,yid
from table
group by xid,yid
having count(1) > 1
```

This will show any pairs that are non-unique, so if there are no rows returned its a good key.

Comment: I like this soultion. Now I can examine the non-unique pairs to determine what I need to add to the key to make it unique.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just do a `count` of the total rows of the table, and then do

```
select count(1)
from(
    select xid,yid
    from table
    group by xid,yid
)a;
```

if all pairs of `xid` and `yid` form a unique identifier, then the two numbers will be the same.

Alternatively, you could count the number of distinct pairs of `xid` and `yid` and find the largest such number:

```
select max(num_rows)
from(
    select xid,yid,count(1) as num_rows
    from table
    group by xid,yid
)a;
```

The result of this query is `1` if and only if (`xid`,`yid`) pairs form a unique identifier for your table.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  I was so close!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this will list all the problem combinations (if any) of xid,yid:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),xid,yid
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY xid,yid
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: As a general point of order, count(1) is preferable than count(*).  Count omits rows where the named contents are null, so if you have rows where all cells are null, they get omitted. I believe you also get a minor performance improvement by using Count(1)

Comment: @jon, COUNT( * ) does *not* omit rows where every value is null. Results and performance should be just the same with COUNT(1) or COUNT( * ). Also if the columns in question permit nulls then they can't be part of a key.